# Como reaproveitar a conexão na subclasse?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Colegas, tenho uma classe de conexão:

```
class Conecta
{
    private $Servidor = '127.0.0.1';
    private $Usuario = 'root';
    private $Senha = 'senha';
    private $Banco = 'banco';

    // Protegido
    protected $Conecta;

    // Faz a conexão
    public function conectar(){

$this->Conecta = mysqli_connect($this->Servidor,$this->Usuario,$this->Senha,$this->Banco);
}
```

E tenho uma classe de métodos:

```
    class Metodos extends Conecta
    {
       // Primeiro método
      public functionPrimeiro(){
           $conectar = new Conecta();
            $conectar->conectar();

    $sql = mysqli_query($conectar->conectar(), "MINHA QUERY");
    }

    // Segundo método
      public functionSegunda(){
           $conectar = new Conecta();
            $conectar->conectar();

    $sql = mysqli_query($conectar->conectar(), "MINHA QUERY");
    }
}
```

Observem que dentro de cada método eu uso:

```
   $conectar = new Conecta();
    $conectar->conectar();
```

Teria algum meio de eu não usar dentro de cada método ou só pode ser dessa forma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifique a classe "Conecta" para:

```
class Conecta
{
    private $Servidor = '127.0.0.1';
    private $Usuario = 'root';
    private $Senha = 'senha';
    private $Banco = 'banco';

    // Protegido
    protected $Conecta;

    // Realiza a conexão no construtor 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Conecta = mysqli_connect($this->Servidor,$this->Usuario,$this->Senha,$this->Banco);
    }
}
```

Para utilizar dentro da sua class de "Metodos", basta fazer:

```
class Metodos extends Conecta
{
    // Primeiro método
    public functionPrimeiro()
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->Conecta, "MINHA QUERY");
    }

    // Segundo método
    public functionPrimeiro()
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->Conecta, "MINHA QUERY");
    }
}
```

Apesar de ser uma solução funcional, recomendo que aceite o concelho do @bfavaretto, se quiser desacoplar ainda mais utilize PDO!

Abraço.

Comment: Olá Hizer. Quando coloquei o __construct, a página ficou em branco.

Comment: Olá! Você tem um exemplo da sua página?

Comment: Olhando o seu código, talvez seja interessante deixar um outro método, idêntico ao construct mas com o nome "conectar", assim você garante a compatibilidade com o seu código legado! Abraço!

Comment: Bingo Hizer. Perfeito. Baseado na sua ideia, criei um método chamado conectar(); Obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Você pode desacoplar esse código e eliminar a herança. Comece com uma classe de conexão que abre a conexão com o banco assim que é instanciada:

```
class Conexao {

    // (...)

    // Tudo o que tinha na sua classe Conecta,
    // + o construtor abaixo
    function __construct() {
        $this->conectar();
    }

    // Se tem coisa específica do mysqli aqui,
    // pode ser interessante abstrair pelo menos
    // um método genérico de query. A ideia é
    // centralizar aqui tudo que lida direto com mysqli.
    public function query($sql) {
        $qry = mysqli_query($this->Conecta, $sql);
        return mysqli_fetch_all($qry, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

}
```

Na classe de métodos, você injeta a conexão, também usando o construtor:

```
class Dados {

    // Conexão guardada aqui
    protected $conexao;

    // Construtor: guarda a conexão
    function __construct($conexao) {
        $this->conexao = $conexao;
    }

    // Um método qualquer que usa o BD
    public function pegaDados() {
        return $this->conexao->query("MINHA QUERY");
    }
}
```

E você usa assim:

```
$bd = new Dados(new Conexao());
var_dump($bd->pegaDados());
```

Comment: Olá bfavaretto, infelizmente não posso desacoplar, pois em outras partes do sistema já está usando dessa forma.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos Me desculpe, mas seu código está tão errado, que eu repensaria ele e refaria onde tivesse que mudar.

Comment: Aproveita enquanto podes, porque o  POO consiste basicamente em reutilizar códigos.

Comment: Olá bigown, concordo com você, mas infelizmente o sistema já estava pronto aqui na empresa e se eu mudar agora, teria que refazê-lo quase que por completo e isso demandaria tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Como a classe Conecta está sendo herdada pela classe Metodos, você pode fazer da seguinte forma usando parent que é uma referência a classe pai em uma relação de herança:

```
parent::conectar();
```

Como ficaria:

```
public functionSegunda(){  
  $sql = mysqli_query(parent::conectar(), "MINHA QUERY");
}
```

Comment: Olá Yure. Tentei usar o parent, porém não funcionou, só funciona se eu colocar a $conectar->conectar()

Comment: Infelizmente não posso desacoplar e nem aplicar PDO, pois estou, como posso dizer, apagando um incêndio... rs rs rs ...já que o sistema já existia e  essa dúvida que passei, foi o que encontrei de errado e estou querendo mudar, porém não estou conseguindo

Comment: Obrigado a todos os colegas que se prontificaram a me ajudar. A ideia do Hizer funcionou.